# How to compute saliency map using keras backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, heatmap

I am trying to construct a basic "vanilla gradient" saliency heatmap (gradient-based feature attribution) for MNIST using keras. I know there are libraries such as this [one](https://raghakot.github.io/keras-vis/visualizations/saliency/) to compute saliency heatmaps, but I would like to construct this from scratch since the vanilla gradient approach seems conceptually straightforward to implement. I have trained the following digit classifier in Keras using functional model definition:

```
input = layers.Input(shape=(28,28,1), name='input')
conv2d_1 = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(input)
maxpooling2d_1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='maxpooling2d_1')(conv2d_1)
conv2d_2 = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(maxpooling2d_1)
maxpooling2d_2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2d_2)
flatten = layers.Flatten(name='flatten')(maxpooling2d_2)
dropout = layers.Dropout(0.5, name='dropout')(flatten)
dense = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='dense')(dropout)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=dense)
```

Now, I want to compute the saliency map for a single MNIST image. Since the final layer has a softmax activation and the denominator is a normalization term (so that the output nodes add up to 1), I believe that I need to either take the pre-softmax output or change the activation of the trained model linear for computing saliency maps. I will do the latter.

```
model.layers[-1].activation = tf.keras.activations.linear # swap activation to linear
input = loaded_model.layers[0].input
output = loaded_model.layers[-1].output
input_image = x_test[0] # shape is (28, 28, 1)
pred = np.argmax(loaded_model.predict(np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0))) # predicted class
```

However, I am not sure what to do beyond this. I know I can use the following `K.gradients(output, input)` to compute gradients. That being said, I believe I should compute the gradient of the predicted class with respect to the input image, versus computing the gradient of the entire output. How would I do this? Also, I'm not sure how to evaluate the saliency heatmap for a specific image/prediction. I imagine I will have to use `sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()` and `sess.run()`, but not sure exactly. I would greatly appreciate any help with completing the saliency heatmap code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the activation as a single layer after the last dense layer with:

`keras.layers.Activation('softmax')`

you can do:

`linear_model = keras.Model(input=model, output=model.layers[-2].output)`

To then compute the gradients like:

```
def get_saliency_map(model, image, class_idx):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(image)
        predictions = model(image)
        
        loss = predictions[:, class_idx]
    
    # Get the gradients of the loss w.r.t to the input image.
    gradient = tape.gradient(loss, image)
    
    # take maximum across channels
    gradient = tf.reduce_max(gradient, axis=-1)
    
    # convert to numpy
    gradient = gradient.numpy()
    
    # normaliz between 0 and 1
    min_val, max_val = np.min(gradient), np.max(gradient)
    smap = (gradient - min_val) / (max_val - min_val + keras.backend.epsilon())
    
    return smap
```